# Why does the compiler need an implementation of a trait to call a default free function?

Tags: types, rust, traits

When calling a default implementation on a trait which does not take `self`, why does it neeed an implementing type to be annotated?

A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is below ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cb25834df6470fbf28965b91bdf7aeb)):

```rust
mod builder {
    pub trait Builder: Sized {
        fn new() -> Simple {
            Simple
        }
    }

    pub struct Simple;

    impl Builder for Simple {}
}

pub fn main() {
    let _ = builder::Builder::new();
    
    /* Working version */
    // use builder::Builder;
    // let _ = builder::Simple::new();
}
```

Which gives:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
3  |         fn new() -> Simple {
   |         ------------------ required by `builder::Builder::new`
...
14 |     let _ = builder::Builder::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: builder::Builder`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

The compiler explanation for `E0283` does not mention a default implementation, which I agree it makes sense. But for default implementations, why is a type required?

Comment: It only looks not-required because there's only one implementation. [Oops, I created another implementation with different side effects](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1fc0611d58c69b55fa647cd0ced414f). Which one should `Builder::new()` call now?

Comment: This answers exactly why it is not allowed. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it clearly for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided methods in Rust are not like `static` methods in Java. Even a function with no arguments and a default implementation can be overridden by implementors. Consider adding another type that implements `Builder` but overrides the `new` function:

```
struct Noisy {}

impl builder::Builder for Noisy {
    fn new() -> builder::Simple {
        println!("Ahahahah I'm creating a Simple!!!11!");
        builder::Simple
    }
}

fn main() {
    // wait, should this call builder::Simple::new() or Noisy::new()?
    let _ = builder::Builder::new();
}
```

If you want the effect of a Java `static` function that always has the same behavior, you should use a free function, as [prog-fh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64412406/3650362) also suggests.

Answer (score 5):

This is not only a *default implementation* but the **very specific case** in which this default implementation does not even mention `Self`/`self` in its parameters, result and body.

I find much more easy to understand a rule saying that a type is required every time we use a trait, in any case, rather that *« except if the default implementation does not even mention `Self`/`self` in its parameters, result and body »*.

For this very specific use case, where you do not want to explicitly name a type when calling the function you need, I suggest using a free function.

```rust
mod builder {
    // ...
    pub fn make_default() -> Simple {
        Simple
    }
    // ...
}

pub fn main() {
    let _ = builder::make_default();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's actually similar to what I have in my project. However, it does litter the API (and also breaks the common practice of having `new` as a method). So I was just wondering why must the compiler enforce it, if there is no need.

Comment: @malinator I would find the opposite very *java-ish*, i.e. everything must be *inside* a class, even when it is not needed, thus increasing the coupling between independent software pieces. *« `new` as a method »* for a type, yes, but not necessarily for everything that returns a value.