# Can I use a trait with default implementations for all functions directly without a concrete implementation?

Tags: rust

I have a trait with default implementations for **all** functions

```
trait Environment {
    fn a() -> String {
        "a".to_string
    }

    fn z() -> String {
        "z".to_string
    }
}
```

Various functions work with implementations of `Environment`. i.e.:

```
fn foo(environment: impl Environment) {}
```

Is it possible to pass `Environment` trait directly or must I create an empty stub implementing Environment? i.e

```
struct Empty;
impl Environment for Empty {} // do nothing here
```

Comment: Your question may be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64412134/11527076). In short, yes, you need a type, the trait alone is not sufficient.

Comment: If you feel particularly lazy you can `impl Environment for ();`, although for public traits may not be such a good idea.

Comment: @rodrigo Could you elaborate on why it is a bad a idea for public traits? I am quite new to Rust and I find what you have described weirdly fascinating.

Comment: Because then your user will see this documented function `pub fn foo(environment: impl Environment)` they will actually have to write `foo(())` to call it. Then a different function with different trait will be `pub fn bar(config: impl Configuration)` and they will have to write `bar(())`. This feels a bit too funny.

Comment: close enough. I'll just create an empty implementation for the trait